# Delete items from a list box with checkboxs enabled. By checking the files you wish to delete

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to delete checked items in my list view my app. The app is simple it deletes temp files in  the current user temp directory. When the app executes it loads all the temp files in the list view.  I have check boxes enabled so that the user can check the items that he/she would like to delete
Thank you for your time.

Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var fName in Directory.GetFiles(tFile))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(fName);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Ignore the failure and continue
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Finished");
            PaintListView(tFile);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check the files you want to delete"); 
        }
    }




    private void selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Checked = true; 
        }
    }

    private void unselectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Checked = false;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int c = listView1.CheckedItems.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            itemsChecked.Text = i.ToString();
        }

        //int listCount = listView1.CheckedItems.Count;
        //itemsChecked.Text = listCount.ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem and post some code.

Comment: The issue is i want to delete the files that are checked

Comment: @user: Code is too long; trim down to the necessary part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the code that you have commented inside a button Click event...for example,

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       int listCount = listView1.CheckedItems.Count;
       itemsChecked.Text = listCount.ToString(); 
}
```

And then in this same event handler, inlcude the logic to delete the files that are checked by iterating through the listview contents.

Comment: Thank you one more thing so the logic to delete the items checked would be a foreach loop ?

Comment: `
int listCount = listView1.CheckedItems.Count;
            itemsChecked.Text = listCount.ToString();

            if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (var fName in Directory.GetFiles(tFile))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(fName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // Ignore the failure and continue
                    }

                } 
`

Comment: **Thats my code above but it just deletes everything no mater whats checked or not.**