# Deleting files that are checked in a listview

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

The code below is what i have in a button I cant seem to understand how to delete these files after they are checked now understand these are actually deleting files in the temp directory that is what i am having issues with now deleting it from the listview i know how to remove them from the list view but the logic behind actually deleting the ones that are checked is what i am stumped on

Thank you for your help

enter code here

```
       if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // If so, loop through all checked files and delete.


            string f = ""; 
            for (int x = 0; x <= listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {

                    // code to delete files 
               tFile = Path.GetTempPath();
                File.Delete(file.ToString());

            }
            MessageBox.Show(f); 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Check the files you want to delete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the data source of your list view look like?  Is it a list of file names?  You need to append the file name to the temp path and pass the entire string to File.Delete().  Right now it looks like you are just trying to call File.Delete() on the temp directory itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to count checked items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561016/how-to-count-checked-items)

Comment: not a duplicate right i need to append the temp path with the file name that is being checked I dont know how to do that.

Comment: The code below outputs to ListViewItem: {filechecked} i need to just extract the file name all of that just filechecked so i can pass that to the path and then finally delete that file.

` selected.
        foreach(object itemChecked in listView1.CheckedItems) 
        MessageBox.Show(itemChecked.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, I think you mean that when you call itemChecked.ToString(), the value is literally

> ListViewItem: {filename}

The ListViewItem.ToString() method shows the .Text property within the brackets, so that property is what you need to reference in your loop.  You might as well use a foreach loop like this:

```
string tempDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems)
{
    string fileName = item.Text;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, fileName);
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```